# Process JSON data coming from server and add/update the objects in CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am working on app which uses **coreData**, I have two entities called **folder** and **notes**. So their is **one to many relationship** between folders-> notes. i.e 1 folder = many notes.

I have used **fetch results controller** for folders, and it is displayed on the UITableView, when user clicks a folder, he goes to notes table, which displays notes inside the particular folder.

**User can add and delete folders/Notes.**

Everything works fine. Everything here is offline.

Now I am trying to **synchronise** this data with server, so that I can sync this to multiple devices. **I dont do a blind sync, I only sync the data which is changed.**

I am using **NSURLConnection** which is by default **asynchronous** and it has delegate functions which gives json data from server.

Now I am trying to process this **JsonData** and I am following a **FindOrCreate** methodology. So if the folder/Notes exists, then just update it or else create the new one and save it the coreData. I am using the **same managedObject and post process happens on the main thread.**

Problems faced. (which are real world cases)

1) When the pull happens, user might be adding new folders/notes and the UI should be responsive, but in my **case UI gets stuck**. So I want to know how can we **fluidly create/update new data coming from server and the UI is also responsive.**

2) I tried doing the post process in background queue, by using

**dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ^{**

}

But here what I observed is that, I get a crash, which says 
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSCFSet: 0x1557ecd0> was mutated while being enumerated.'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common error. It means that that you cannot loop a collection and modify it at the same time.  Say you wish to loop and find objects to delete.  Don't delete in the loop, plAce things to be deleted in a temporary collection, and delete them after the loop.

Comment: Hey @danh, solved the issue, and also now I am doing importing of large data on background thread

Comment: hey @danh please look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28413256/handle-401-status-code-with-sendasynchronousrequestrequest-api-in-ios