# Handle 401 status code with sendAsynchronousRequest:request API in iOS

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, sendasynchronousrequest

I am using this way API to login in my app.

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@//login",xyz];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];


    NSError *error;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
    if (!jsonData) {
        NSLog(@"Error creating JSON object: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }


    [request setValue:@"application/json;charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:APIKEY forHTTPHeaderField:@"X_API_KEY"];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
     // the NSOperationQueue upon which the handler block will be dispatched:
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
     {
         NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;

         NSDictionary *responseDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options: 0 error: &error];  //I am using sbjson to parse

         if(httpResponse.statusCode == 200)
         {

             //Show message to user success
         }
         else  if(httpResponse.statusCode == 401)
         {
            //Show message to user -fail
         }
         else if(httpResponse.statusCode == 500)
         {
             //Show message to user- server error
         }
     }];
```

**When I use correct user name and password, I get httpResponse and status code as 200. But if use wrong user name and password, I am not getting 401.**

So how to handle this situation

Regards
Ranjit

Comment: 401 sounds like a reasonable response to bad credentials, but what makes you certain that this is the server's design?  Maybe the response body contains a clue.

Comment: @danh, as you san see in the above code, I was checking it based on the status code, and as of now I dont get any status code, when credentials are wrong, I do get error code :104 in reponse. So you suggest me to use that while checking?

Answer (score 0):

You are casting your `NSURLResponse` to an `NSHTTPURLResponse` but this won't automatically expose the actual value you expect in the `statusCode` property.

Instead, you should check if the `error` property has been populated and check the `code` property instead.

```
if(error)
{
    NSLog(@"error: %@", error.code);

    if(error.code == 401)
    {
        //handle 401 errors
    }
    else if(error.code == 500)
    {
        //handle 500 errors
    }
}
else
{
    //successful request
}
```

Comment: The error codes should actually be `kCFURLErrorUserCancelledAuthentication` for 401 and `kCFURLErrorBadServerResponse` for 500